# Sort an Array alphabeticaly but move those with 0 values to the end

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort my multidimensional array using two rules.

My array looks like this:

```
$array = [
    ['label' => 12, 'countValue' => 5],
    ['label' => 4, 'countValue' => 78],
    ['label' => 9, 'countValue' => 5],
    ['label' => 64, 'countValue' => 0],
    ['label' => 3, 'countValue' => 60],
    ['label' => 19, 'countValue' => 0],
    ['label' => 7, 'countValue' => 5],
];
```

1. I need rows with `['countValue'] = 0` to be move to the back and
2. Sort the rows based on their `label` value in an ascending direction.

Desired result:

```
$array = [
    ['label' => 3, 'countValue' => 60],
    ['label' => 4, 'countValue' => 78],
    ['label' => 7, 'countValue' => 5],
    ['label' => 9, 'countValue' => 5],
    ['label' => 12, 'countValue' => 5],
    ['label' => 19, 'countValue' => 0],
    ['label' => 64, 'countValue' => 0],
];
```

I have the following code:

```
public function sortOptionsByName($a, $b)
{
    $x = trim($a['label']);
    $y = trim($b['label']);

    if ($x == '') return 1;
    if ($y == '') return -1;

    if (is_numeric($x) && is_numeric($y)){
        if ($x == $y)
            return 0;
        return ($x > $y ? 1 : -1);
    }
    else {
        return strcasecmp($x, $y);
    }
}

public function sortOptionsByCounts($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['countValue'] == $b['countValue']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['countValue'] < $b['countValue'] ? 1 : -1);
}
```

Something like...

```
public function sortOptionsByCountsAndByName($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['countValue'] == 0 &&  $b['countValue'] == 0) {
        return -2
    }
    else {
        $this->sortOptionsByName($a, $b)
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare values with zero. PHP casts boolean to integer, so you can just subtract to get -1, 0 , 1. And then compare another value when thw 1st comparing returns 0

```
public function sortOptionsByCountsAndByName($a, $b)
{
    $res = ($a['countValue'] == 0) - ($b['countValue'] == 0);
    return ($res ? $res : $this->sortOptionsByName($a, $b));
}
```

Comment: I get something like this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/qIxpd) The first number is the 'name' and inside the parenthesis is the 'countValue'

Comment: Sorry - ret should be returned if it is not zero - updated

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your data twice, once by name and once by count value. I would suggest to use `usort()` and implement two custom compare methods:

```
<?php

  function cmpName($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['Name'], $b['Name']);
  }

  function cmpCountValue($a, $b) {
    if ($a['CountValue'] == 0)
      return 1;
    if ($b['CountValue'] == 0)
      return -1;
    return cmpName($a, $b);
  }

 $a[0]['Name'] = 'Bob';
 $a[0]['CountValue'] = 0;

 $a[1]['Name'] = 'Christal';
 $a[1]['CountValue'] = 42;

 $a[2]['Name'] = 'Alice';
 $a[2]['CountValue'] = 23;

 $a[3]['Name'] = 'Jack';
 $a[3]['CountValue'] = 1;

 $a[4]['Name'] = 'Alex';
 $a[4]['CountValue'] = 58;

  usort($a, "cmpName");
  usort($a, "cmpCountValue");

  foreach ($a as $item) {
    echo $item['Name'] . ": " . $item['CountValue'] . "<br />";
  }

?>
```

The output is:

```
Alex: 58
Alice: 23
Christal: 42
Jack: 1
Bob: 0
```

Online demo: [See here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e91524e6cc807ffc4de8d3d8cfbe20c8cc659571)

Comment: i added 2 more values to your example: 
 `$a[3]['Name'] = 'Jack';
$a[3]['CountValue'] = 1;

$a[4]['Name'] = 'Alex';
$a[4]['CountValue'] = 58;` and i am getting wrong order `Jack: 1
Alice: 23
Christal: 42
Alex: 58
Bob: 0`

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try again. We don't need to sort by count value, we simply put zero values to the end of the list now. I think that's what you were asking for.

Comment: Again those with CountValue > 0 is not alphabetical

Comment: Did you apply the changes correctly? I've added my output (tested with PHP 7.0).

Comment: Sorry but i am on PHP 5.6

Comment: Please try again, should work with PHP 5.x as well now. The problem was that the relative order in the sorted array is undefined, if two members compare as equal. PHP 7.0 and PHP 5.x handle this differently.

Comment: Yeah its working now... Thanks! I now need to implement this to my app  :D

Comment: Can you give me a function like @splash58 so it considers both arrays?

Comment: I dont understand... My function has 2 parameters and yours 1 :D

Comment: @user1438038 your solusion makes the 2nd part of the result array unsorted

Comment: It sorts by name alphabetically and then puts all zero values to the end of the list, as requested. Sorting by count values within elements that have the same name was no requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just bake your sorting rules into two arrays with symmetric elements and separate them with a spaceship operator.

When sorting ASC, `false` comes before `true`, so by checking if the `countValue` is "falsey", `true` evaluations will be pushed to the back of the pack.

The order of the elements in the sorting callback says:

1. Prioritize non-zero `countValue` rows.
2. When there is a tie on the first rule, break the tie by sorting on `label` ASC.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qcEnd))

```
usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) =>
        [!$a['countValue'], $a['label']]
        <=>
        [!$b['countValue'], $b['label']]
);
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => 3,
    'countValue' => 60,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => 4,
    'countValue' => 78,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'label' => 7,
    'countValue' => 5,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'label' => 9,
    'countValue' => 5,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'label' => 12,
    'countValue' => 5,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'label' => 19,
    'countValue' => 0,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'label' => 64,
    'countValue' => 0,
  ),
)
```